# Start/Stop Azure Function App using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

Is there a way to start/stop azure function app using python programming by passing a parameter to the http trigger url of the function

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to access query parameter in your function file. Here is the binding for a sample azure function:-

```js
{
    "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
    "bindings": [
        {
            "authLevel": "function",
            "type": "httpTrigger",
            "direction": "in",
            "name": "req",
            "methods": [
                "get",
                "post"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "http",
            "direction": "out",
            "name": "$return"
        }
    ]
}
```

and suppose this is the function

```js
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}!")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body",
             status_code=400
        )
```

Above sample function accepts an http POST request, and requires your request body to be a JSON payload with a "name" property.

To access URL query parameters, we make them available to you as distinct environment variables. For example, if you send query parameter "foo", you can access it via os.environ['req_query_foo'].

and then based on the query param , you can start and stop the function .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i wanted to start and stop the azure function on demand based on the parameter in the HTTP URL, is there a possiblity to achieve this ?